# how to work with Progressive bar?

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I am copying the data from one location to another location in "WPF".On click of the copy button the progress bar should be enabled and after copying all the data immediately the progressive bar should be closed?pls help me out?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265748/WPF-Progress-Bar-using-Threads

Comment: try this [WPF-ProgressBar](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38555/WPF-ProgressBar)

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the IsEnabled property of your ProgressBar

Set the Visibility to System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed to hide it.