# How to work with Progress Bar?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik

I am working on Progress Bar in WPF windows application. My problem is I have a data in microsoft access database format, and I want to copy the data into the data base, the copying should happens only after on click of the button.During the data is copying to the database the Progress Bar should get enabled.

Comment: This would only make sense if you were able to predict how long it takes to write the data. Are you? Or is there any other means of getting a progress percentage? Are you perhaps writing data piece by piece?

Comment: You asked it already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683274/how-to-work-with-progressive-bar

Comment: You asked this four days ago; you gave very little to go on then, and didn't respond when you were asked to show the code you'd tried so far. This isn't going to get you a useful answer - you need to ask a useful question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i think Background Worker is what you are looking for here is the link 
[BackGroundWorker](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/backgroundworker.html)

Answer (score 0):

in order to use a progress bar you are going to need to create a new thread which is separate from the ui thread. The Background worker is probably the best way of doing this:

```
 private BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

 worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
 worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
 worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
 Worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(Worker_ProgressChanged);
```

Inside the worker_DoWork event is where you should put the stuff that you want doing. in this case copying data. This is also the event where I set my progress bar control to be visible (should be not visible by default). In order to update the value on the progress bar, you need to do

```
 worker.ReportProgress(int amountDone)
```

Now it'll be up to you to work out a tangible way of getting a percentage/amount of the job thats been completed, as Vale commented on your post, in this case the row count may be the best way of doing it: NumberOfRowsCopied/TotalNumberOfRows * 100 = percentage done?

To start the background worker, in your button click event/command:

```
if (bw.IsBusy != true)
{
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

If your not confident in working out an amount of progress made, then perhaps use a marquis control instead, which will simply show the user that the program hasn't crashed and is still working.